# How to get rows which only have a certain value after group by, in Pandas

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, database

For example after grouping two columns the result is:

Car 1.   Nissan
Purchased
Sold

Car 2    Nissan
Sold

Car 3    Nissan
Purchased
Sold
Rented

I would like to retrieve the Cars which have ONLY been sold. So just return Car 2.
However everything I have tried returns Car 1 and Car 3 as well, as they have both been sold as well.

Comment: without sample data it is difficult to answer. Share table and data scripts with expected result on that data

Comment: I meant as in there are multiple Car 1, Car 2, Car 3 records, as their status is registered (e.g purchased, sold, rented). So I want to retrieve cars which have ONLY been sold.

Comment: What is your code for ouput in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consedering the given dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Car": ['Car 1', 'Car 2', 'Car 3', 'Car 2', 'Car 2'],
                   "Model": ['Nissan', 'Nissan', 'Nissan', 'Nissan', 'Nissan'],
                   "Status": ['Purchased', 'Sold', 'Sold', 'Sold', 'Rented']})
```

##### >>> `df`

[image]

You can get the cars that have been sold (and not purchased or rented) by running this code :

```
df['Occur'] = df[df['Status'] == 'Sold'].groupby('Car')['Model'].transform('size')

filtered_df = df.loc[df['Occur'] == 1][['Car', 'Model', 'Status']]

filtered_df
```

##### >>> `filtered_df`

[image]

Comment: This is close, sorry I meant however that purchased, sold and rented are 3 values. And there are multiple entries of car 1,  car 2 and car 3.

Comment: Like: Car 1 - Sold 
         Car 1 - Purchased 

        Car 2 - Sold

But I only want to return cars that have ONLY been sold (e.g. Car 2 )

Comment: Yes, It's clear now for me. I will update my answer.

Comment: I edited my answer. Check it out ! Hopefully, it's the result you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, however I meant Purchased, Sold, and Rented are 3 individual rows.

As in for example

Car 1 - Nissan - Purchased ,
Car 1 - Nissan - Sold , 
Car 2 - Nissan - Sold , 
Car 3 - Nissan - Purchased ,
Car 3 - Nissan - Sold

Comment: I got you @SharadR. Look at the final edit I made.